# List to Dictionary conversion in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list which is holding names as below

```
d=[['Srini'], ['Rahul'], ['Mano'], ['Rahul'], ['Srini'], ['Mano], ['Srini'], ['Rahul']]
```

I am using the below code to convert the list to dictionary which should hold names as Keys and the count of names as value.

```
dic={}
for words in d:
    dic[words]= dic.get(words,0)+1
print(dic)
```

> ERROR:
>   TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 dic={}
>         2 for words in d:
>   ----> 3     dic[words]= dic.get(words,0)+1
>         4 print(dic)
>
> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: You can't use a list as the key to a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

List are unhashable. You could, however, assume that each sub-list has a single element and refer to it:

```
dic={}
for words in d:
    dic[words[0]]= dic.get(words[0], 0) + 1
print(dic)
```

Note, BTW, that python's `Counter` already has a pretty similar functionality:

```
from collections import Counter
print(Counter((i[0] for i in d)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
dic = {}
for i in range(len(d)):
    if d[i] in dic:
        dic[d[i]] += 1
    else:
        dic[d[i]] = 1
```